# AT&F command , c# modem and phone line

Tags: c#, com, serial-port, modem

i have pretty hard task, i need to call to device in the field and take out some data from it in c#. What i did so far i installed some com sniffer and recored some communication. I am showing here first part where com port is established and application is calling, my question is how can i send it in c# to recive what i saw in sniffer.

```
Request: 2/02/2012 17:19:22.05464 (+0.6390 seconds)


 41 54 44 54 30 31 34 35 31 38 30 36 33 0D         ATDT014518063.  


Answer: 2/02/2012 17:19:54.24264 (+31.3708 seconds)


 0D 0A 43 4F 4E 4E 45 43 54 20 39 36 30 30 2F 41   ..CONNECT 9600/A
 52 51 2F 56 33 32 2F 4C 41 50 4D 2F 56 34 32 42   RQ/V32/LAPM/V42B
 49 53 0D 0A                                       IS..
```

Comment: Can you maybe get rid of all that specific text and generalize what you're wanting to do a bit?  You want to build a string...?

Comment: i am wondering how can i send this request in c# and recieve what i got here

Comment: There's a ton of example code if you search for `[c#] [serial]`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23+serial

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to get started is to open up a [SerialPort](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.aspx) and send the above data.  When the data comes back, parse it.

**EDIT:** The listen to the [DataReceived](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.datareceived.aspx) event.

Comment: ok i know how to send it but what shoould i do to wait for receiving?

Comment: @kosnkov - attach a handler to the DataRecieved event to get the incoming data (I've updated my answer with a link to the MSDN docs for that event)